# Energy balance for beta decay of cobalt-60

Tags: nuclear-physics, radiation, radioactivity

I am confused by a simple fact about the $\beta^{-}$ decay of ${}^{60}{\rm Co}$ nucleus. According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cobalt-60), the most likely decay branch is to an excited state of ${}^{60}{\rm Ni}$, see the diagram:

[image: Decay scheme of Co-60]

But the energy indicated on the diagram (0.31 MeV) is less than the electron rest mass (0.511 MeV)! How is that possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When they show a decay with a certian amount of energy, this energy is net of the masses of the particles.  So you get Co = $\beta$ + Ni + 0.31 MeV, the energy is attached to the ejected beta particle.

Comment: Fair enough, thanks. So 0.31 MeV is just the kinectic energy of the electron and the anti-neutrino.